# Hiding certain table rows onpageload where a column exceeds a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table like this:

```
S.No  Name  Year

 1      A   2004

 2      B   2005

 3      C   2004
```

I need to hide all rows having years greater than 2004 using **jquery**. I need to use something like this:

```
$('tr').find('td:eq(2):contains(>2004)').parent().hide();
```

But there is a problem incorporating the `>` symbol in the contains parameter. Please help me in debugging this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$('tr').find('td:eq(2)').filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).text()) > 2004;
}).parent().hide();
```

---

`.filter()` all the elements which have text year greater than 2004

---

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/fz9pY/)</kbd>

Comment: Worked great Tushar. Thanks a lot.

Comment: funtion should be function

Comment: @SamBattat ty it was a typo

Comment: I know, I was gonna edit the answer but the edit has to be more that 6 char long :)

Comment: @SamBattat yeah some time you get stuck with the minimum limit.Thanks again .

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr td:eq(2)').each(function(i){
    (parseInt($(this).text()>2004) ?  $(this).parent().hide() : '';
}
```